# Cost-wise is it better to update timestamps using `updateDoc` from front or from a google cloud function?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Is it better to use `updateDoc` (front), e.g.

```js
function addElement(element) {
  updateDoc(
    doc(firestore, 'customers', user.uid, 'collections', collection.id),
    {
      elements: arrayUnion(element),
      updated: new Date() // <-
    }
  )
}
```

or make a GC function (back), e.g.

```js
import admin from 'firebase-admin';
import {onDocumentUpdated} from 'firebase-functions/v2/firestore';

admin.initializeApp();

exports.updateDocumentTimeStamp = onDocumentUpdated(
    '/customers/{uid}/collections/{id}',
    (event) => {
        const data = event.data.after.data();
        const previousData = event.data.before.data();

        if (data.name === previousData.name) return null;

        return data.after.ref.set(
            {
                updated: admin.firestore.Timestamp.now(),
            },
            {merge: true}
        );
    }
);
```

It's the first time I am making a premium app, and for this I decided to use Firebase. Because it's the first time and I don't have a great budget, and my app uses *Firestore* and *GC functions* for free content I'm worried to lose more money than I can make.
For this reason my question is about finding the less expensive method.

Which one of these two solutions is more likely to have less impact on the bill when the number of users grow?

If I try to answer this question myself I'd say functions are more expensive because I am making two Firestore transactions (one for the main update, and another one to update the timestamp) but because the second transaction is made from a function (internally into Google services) it tricks me into thinking it has no-cost. Too much confusion led me to ask this question here.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> because the second transaction is made from a function (internally into Google services) it tricks me into thinking it has no-cost

That's not true.  All document updates are billed, regardless where they originate.

Also consider that the Cloud Function invocation is billed, regardless of what it does when invoked.